# How to populate a core data store programmatically generating index per record

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, sqlite

I need to populate the coredata store programmatically but everytime I need to update the coredata store I want to generate programmatically an incremental numeric index value for record. Any of you knows how can I do this or if this posible?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Core data already has unique ids accessible via the `objectID` property. You can use those IDs if you require unique keys, say, for other databases. You could pass this ID after transforming it with the help of the `NSManagedObjectID` method `URIRepresentation`.

If you do not need to communicate with other non-Core-Data databases, abandon the idea of incrementing IDs altogether. You will find that you do not need them.

Comment: can the objectID be a numeric value such any sql database it would use a index for the table?

Answer (score -1):

For the first time you have to save the data in CoreData.

Next time onwards you  have to check the condition whether that record is saved or not.

If it is saved you have to call `Save` method otherwise call `Update`

Many tutorials are available. The following link is also good. Please check for saving, updating, deleting.

http://www.appcoda.com/core-data-tutorial-update-delete/

If you will save in Coredata, automatically index will incremented.